# PostgreSQL full text search: How to change what classifies as a "word separator"?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, full-text-search

Using `ts_debug` I can see what symbols Postgres treats as (what I call) a "word separator".

Example:

```
SELECT ts_debug('english', 'Hello. ABC')
```

Result:

```
(asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",Hello,{english_stem},english_stem,{hello})
(blank,"Space symbols",". ",{},,)
(asciiword,"Word, all ASCII",ABC,{english_stem},english_stem,{abc})
```

". " (dot space) is treated as a word separator.
My problem is, I need Postgres to treat a single dot "." as a word separator too.

Right now, if I search for `ABC` no entry with the content `Hello.ABC` (without space after the dot) will be found, only with `Hello. ABC`.

I am using this search query:

```
SELECT description FROM incident WHERE
  to_tsvector('english', description) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'ABC')
```

Another example: Searching for `IOException` will not find `java.io.IOException`

Is there a way to treat a single dot (without space) as a word separator?

Comment: AFAIK you'll have to define your own dictionary for this.  How easy it is I cannot tell, unfortunately.  Alternatively, you could treat the periods without a space by adding one, and only apply `to_tsvector()` afterwards.  It's a simple `regexp_replace()`, but might be costly.

Comment: That is a good workaround. I can add `regexp_replace()` to the index definition. So it's pretty fast!